# OCCPP CentralSystem send remote start transaction when Criteria Fulfilled

Tags: python, python-asyncio, ocpp

I use `await asyncio.gather(cp.start(), cp.send_remote_start_transaction())`, and it successfully sends a charging command to the charging station. However, I want to issue the charging command only when a certain condition is met (e.g., when variable 'a' keeps accumulating to 10). It seems that it gets blocked by `cp.start()` and doesn't allow other code to execute. Does anyone have a solution for this? My expected code is as follows:

```
import asyncio
from re import L
import websockets
from datetime import datetime
import logging

#logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger('session')


from ocpp.routing import on
from ocpp.v16 import ChargePoint as cp
from ocpp.v16.enums import *
from ocpp.v16 import call_result, call

class ChargePoint(cp):

    # Operations Initiated by Central System
    async def send_remote_start_transaction(self):
        request = call.RemoteStartTransactionPayload(
            id_tag='test'
        )

        response = await self.call(request)

        if response.status == RemoteStartStopStatus.accepted:
            print("Transaction Started!!!.")

        elif response.status == ChargingProfileStatus.rejected:
            print("Transaction not Started!!!.")

    @on(Action.BootNotification)
    def on_boot_notitication(self, charge_point_vendor, charge_point_model, **kwargs):

        print(f'{charge_point_model} from {charge_point_vendor} booted.')

        return call_result.BootNotificationPayload(
            current_time=datetime.utcnow().isoformat(),
            interval=10,
            status=RegistrationStatus.accepted
        )

    @on(Action.Heartbeat)
    def on_heartbeat(self, **kwargs):
        return call_result.HeartbeatPayload(
            current_time=datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
        )

# Server functions

async def on_connect(websocket, path):
    """ For every new charge point that connects, create a ChargePoint instance
    and start listening for messages.

    """
    #await websocket.send('Connection made succesfully.')
    charge_point_id = path.strip('/')

    cp = ChargePoint(charge_point_id, websocket)  
    await cp.start() #僅接收心跳包
    a = 0
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        a += 1
        print(a)
        if a == 10:
            await cp.send_remote_start_transaction()


async def main():
    server = await websockets.serve(
        on_connect,
        '0.0.0.0',
        8888,
        subprotocols=['ocpp1.6']
    )

    await server.wait_closed()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I think this is just a basic asyncio multithreading issue. I've searched related articles, but I still can't understand. In the articles I found, most of them didn't establish a WebSocket connection, so this indirectly makes me uncertain if their suggested methods are feasible.

By the way, here's the OCPP library I'm using: [https://github.com/mobilityhouse/ocpp](https://stackoverflow.com)